# Wie funktioniert »Das König der Biere«?

Tags: gender

Der Werbeslogan ***Das König der Biere*** (zum Glück erinnere ich mich nicht an die Marke, sonst hätte die Werbung gegriffen) »funktioniert« bei den meisten Menschen – er wird i. d. R. zwar als merkwürdig und ungewöhnlich, ggf. auch scheußlich, wahrgenommen, aber verstanden.

Nur worum handelt es sich hierbei? Angenommen, derartige Konstruktionen würden in den alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch übergehen, bräuchten wir dann einen neuen Begriff in der Grammatik dafür?

Vielleicht ist unser Gehirn ganz gut in der Lage, das *das* auf *Bier* zu beziehen. Wie wäre es dann aber mit der Konstruktion *Der Königin der Weine* (das *der* auf *Wein* beziehend)? *Das König der Biere* funktioniert irgendwie deutlich besser als die neu erfundene Variante (oder?).

Eine Überlegung ist, *König der Biere* als »irgendwie unbekanntes, kompaktes« Objekt zu verstehen und daher mit einem sächlichen Artikel zu versehen, der in solchen Fällen am ehesten verwendet wird (Das Blablublo). Dagegen spricht allerdings, dass *Das König der Weine* nicht funktioniert (oder?).

Wie also »funktioniert« *Das König der Biere?*

Comment: "Der Königin der Weine" funktioniert meiner Meinung nach aus 2 Gründen nicht: Erstens wegen der Wiederholung des Artikels und zweitens weil es wie der Dativ (z.B. "Es gehört der Königin der Weine") klingt und damit ein Teil des Satzes zu fehlen scheint.

Comment: Die Werbefritzen wissen, dass man mit falschen Strukturen in Werbesprüchen Aufmerksamkeit erzielen kann, wie Cass schon richtig bemerkt hat. Das bekannteste Beispiel ist "... da werden Sie geholfen", den eine junge Dame mit charmantem Lächeln uns eingehämmert hat, mit Erfolg, der Satz blieb in Erinnerung.Solche Tricks sind aber schnell ein alter Hut, deshalb greifen Werbefritzen nicht allzu oft in diese Trickkiste.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Es handelt sich beim Slogan

> Das König der Biere

um ein Wortspiel.

König ist nämlich sowohl ein Wort, das "Regent" bedeutet, als auch der Name einer Biermarke ([König Pilsener](http://www.koenig.de/)). Die Marke "König Pilsener" ist sächlich; somit ist der Artikel "das" durchaus korrekt.

Der Spruch ist vielleicht auch eine Anspielung auf

> (Der Löwe ist) der König der Tiere.

was wegen des ähnlichen Klangs Tiere/Biere auch dazu beiträgt, dass der Slogan "funktioniert".

Comment: Es ist auch eine Anspielung auf Warsteiners Werbespruch, "Eine Königin unter den Bieren".

Comment: @Cass: Ist die Reihenfolge der Werbeslogans irgendwie belegbar.

Comment: @userunknown: [Eine Königin 1962-2014](http://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/Nach-52-Jahren-Warsteiner-ist-nicht-mehr-Eine-Koenigin-unter-den-Bieren-118324) (s.a. [auf slogans.de](https://www.slogans.de/slogans.php?BSelect%5B%5D=105)) und [Das König 2005-2010](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig-Brauerei#Werbung) ([auf slogans.de](https://www.slogans.de/slogans.php?BSelect[]=62) vermutlich auf der zweiten Seite).

Answer (score 13):

Ich glaube nicht, dass "Das König der Biere" grammatikalisch funktioniert, oder funktionieren *soll* - der Satz ist absichtlich und provokant falsch, damit man hinhört, zusammenzuckt, ihn sich merkt, und sich dann darüber unterhält. Werbung versucht ja immer gerne, zu provozieren, und in dieser Hinsicht funktioniert der Satz ganz ausgezeichnet: Wir verbreiten gerade freiwillig ihren Werbespruch weiter.

Ich würde vermuten, dass "Der Königin der Weine" für Dich hauptsächlich deshalb noch falscher klingt, weil Du Dich durch Wiederholung inzwischen an den Werbespruch gewöhnt hast. Wenn man etwas oft genug hört, merkt man irgendwann nicht mehr, dass es seltsam oder falsch ist. Verständlich sind beide Sätze - ein Satz wird nicht unverständlich, bloß weil der falsche Artikel verwendet wird.

Wenn solche Konstruktionen in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch übergehen würden, bräuchte man tatsächlich einen neuen Begriff dafür, aber ich sehe keinen Hinweis darauf, dass sie das tun - abgesehen von Menschen, die die Sprache gerade erst lernen, diesem einen Werbespruch, und gelegentlicher Verwirrung, ob es "der Nutella", "die Nutella", oder "das Nutella" heißt, ist es eigentlich nicht üblich, den bestimmten Artikel des falschen Geschlechts zu verwenden.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass die Analogie "Königin der Weine" funktioniert. "König" ist in diesem Zusammenhang der Eigenname eines bestimmten Biers, "Königin" hingegen nicht der Eigenname eines bestimmten Weins. Ich denke, dass "König" als Bier schon vor Aufkommen des Werbespruchs als sächlich etabliert war. Wenn mich der Kellner fragt, was ich trinken möchte, dann antworte ich doch auch "ein König" und nicht etwa "einen König" -- im letzteren Fall dürfte mich der Kellner doch etwas verwirrt anschauen...

Comment: Deinem ersten Absatz stimme ich zu, aber Splattnes Löwe hat doch zuviel für sich, sonst würde ich Dir Deine Antwort mit Deutschlands meister Kreditkarte :) abkaufen.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt Astra, Holsten, Warsteiner, König (als umgangsprachliche Kurzform für König Pilsener) und viele andere NAMEN unter den Bieren. Es könnte auch heißen: "Das Astra der Biere". 
"Wem gehört hier das König? Wem gehört hier das Astra?", fragt der Wirt. "Keine Ahnung! Das König gehört mir!", antworte ich. 
Der Slogan ist so gesehen in korrektem Deutsch. Wir assoziieren nur mit dem Wort "König", als Name des Bieres, schnell den König in Person. Diese Verknüpfung ist vom Hersteller auch gewollt. Wenn mit dem Spruch eindeutig der König in Person gemeint sein sollte, müsste es heißen: König Pilsener, der König der Biere. Der Spruch meint aber tatsächlich das Bier, kreiiert aber aufgrund unseres Assoziationsketten bildenden Hirns eben auch eine  zweite Bedeutung.

Comment: Richtig, aber zu lang.  Wesentlich:  "Das König" gibt's als Ellipsierung vom (richtigen) "Das König Pilsener Bier".

Answer (score 2):

„Das König“ ist in dem Slogan der Brauerei durchaus grammatikalisch korrekt. Hier bezieht sich der Artikel „das“ und das Nomen „König“ nämlich auf – und jetzt aufgepasst – „Das Bier/Das Pils“ und nicht auf den König per se.

Die Brauerei König hingegen hält ihr Produkt womöglich auch einfach bloß für königlich, so wie Warsteiner auch, wenn die sagen: eine Königin unter den Bieren.

Am Ende bedeuten beide Slogans dasselbe. König Pilsener jedoch war ein wenig aufmerksamer oder schneller und hat sich durch diese ungewohnte Assoziation von König und Bier (welche durchaus inhaltlich und grammatikalisch korrekt ist) einen Marketingtrick zu Nutze gemacht; denn der vermeintlich falsche Artikel vor König wird vielen Menschen zunächst komisch und falsch vorkommen, da man König doch immer mit *der* kennt.

Beim genauen Analysieren des Slogans wird aber dann meiner Meinung nach recht schnell klar, wie es letztendlich funktioniert.

Comment: Auf das Bier/das Pils - kann man sich das aussuchen? Wie wäre es mit der Maibock/das Bier? Oder die Berliner Weiße/das Bier? Insgesamt finde ich nichts in der Antwort, was nicht schon vor - jetzt aufgepasst - 5 Jahren gesagt wurde.

Comment: Die Behauptung, dass sich *das* auf das Bier beziehen könne, halte ich für außerordentlich gewagt: Das grammatische Geschlecht von *König der Biere* wird ziemlich eindeutig

Comment: Da ich die Bearbeitungszeit für meinen Kommentar verpasst habe: Die Behauptung, dass sich *das* auf *das Bier* beziehen könnte, halte ich für ziemlich gewagt. Wenn das so wäre, müsste der Name stattdessen doch eigentlich *die König der Biere* heißen, denn schlielich sind *die Biere* ja auch ein Plural. Deine genauere Analyse überzeugt mich daher nicht wirklich...

Comment: @Schmuddi: Der Artikel *das* bezieht sich aber (auch laut dieser Antwort) nicht auf die im Slogan auftauchenden "Biere", sondern auf ein nicht genanntes, implizites "Bier", nämlich *das* "König-Bier".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Was ist die Evidenz für ein implizites *Bier*, abgesehen davon, dass die Existenz eines solchen den Genus des Artikels erklären würde? Wenn man mit Zero-Elementen hantiert, besteht die Gefahr, dass die Argumentationskette zirkulär wird, aber vielleicht übersehe ich hier auch eine überzeugende Begründung.

Answer (score 1):

Hat es nicht etwas damit zu tun, dass sich das "Das" auf das Bier bezieht. Es ist "Das König Bier der Biere." Bier is sächlich, und damit hat es den Artikel "Das". Oder versteh' ich das komplett falsch?

Comment: So hatte ich das auch verstanden (s. Frage: "Vielleicht ist unser Gehirn ganz gut in der Lage, das "Das" auf "Bier" zu beziehen.") Die Frage bezieht sich eher darauf, **wieso** es so eingängig ist, etwa im Ggs. zu vergleichbaren Konstruktionen.

Comment: Es heißt auch "Die Koryphäe unter den Professoren" - das Geschlecht des Wortes Professoren ist dabei Jacke wie Hose, "Die Hose im Sortiment", "Die Tasse im Service", "Der Löffel, die Gabel und das Messer des Silberbestecks" ... - das König ist wohl eine Ellipse für Königspilsener also kein Bezug auf Bier, sondern auf Pilsener.

Comment: @userunknown: Und was anderes ist "Pilsener" als eine Ellipse für "Pilsener Bier"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Also eine Ellillipse? Das Königspilsener Bier unter den Ellipsen?